# ASP.NET errors related to null and non-null values. Don't understand

Tags: c#, asp.net, null

I get this error when I 'update-database -Verbose' using Powershell:

> The value of the complex property 'Address' on entity of type
>   'Student' is null. Complex properties cannot be set to null and values
>   cannot be set for null complex properties.

or

```
{"Null value for non-nullable member. Member: 'Address'."}
```

This error also occurs when I try to create a new student or instructor. I think the problem is in the controller but that is 100's of line of code and I am not exactly sure where it is.  Here is the code for Student.cs:

```
public class Student : Person
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Enrollment Date")]
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

    // Credits earned
    [Display(Name = "Credits Earned")]
    [Range(typeof(double), "0.00", "1000.00")]
    public double? CreditsEarned { get; set; }

    // GPA
    [Display(Name = "GPA")]
    [Range(typeof(double), "0.7", "4.0")]
    public double? Gpa { get; set; }

   public Address Address { get; set; }  // here is me using Address


    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}
```

Person class:

```
public abstract class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    // A Person 'has a' Address object 
    public Address Address { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]

    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
    [Column("FirstName")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
}
```

And here is the Address class I created:

```
public class Address
{
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Compare("Email")]
    public string EmailConfirm { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is "Address", where is it defined and how?

Comment: in the abstract class Person public Address Address {get; set; } and I created an Address class --> you can see in the edits

Comment: Have you tried setting it to virtual?

Comment: Yes and it doesn't work, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your `Person` class is never creating an instance of Address so it is `null`.  Add a constructor that creates an address to your `Person` class

```
public Person() 
{
    Address = new Address();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you initializing your `Address` property when you create a `Student` instance?